# using JAVA Loop for math calculation

Tags: java

I had tried to do some calculations and something doesn't quite add up. I am trying to achieve the screenshot below
[image: expected]

but this is what i'm getting

[image: result]

Please I need some help, this is what I have done so far

```
public class VelocityFall
{
public static void main (String [] a)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("This program prints a table that shows each \nsecond,"     
  +
    "height from the ground (meters), and the velocity (m/s)\n of a free-falling" + 
    "object from an initial height (metres).\nPlease input the Initial Height H:  ");


    // input/get the value of H from the keyboard
    double H = s.nextDouble ();
    // we need to design/output the table by using println with lines and tabs (\t)

    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println (" t(s)\t\tHeight(m)\t\tVelocity(m/s)");
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------");

    //we now require a for loop
    for (int t = 0; t<=15; t++)
   {
    // we are now going to calculate and output the velocity and decreasing  
    height
   double velocity = 9.8*t;
   H = H-(0.5*9.8*Math.pow(t,2));  
   System.out.println(t + "\t\t" + H + "\t\t" + velocity);

   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I took kinematics, but shouldn't you be calculating your H from the initial height, not from the previous height?

Comment: Can  you please edit your question so that it's better formatted, and can you please explain *what you are trying to do*. "Some calculation" is not a thing, that's just loose words, what exact calculation are you trying to do, with which inputs, how do the outputs differ, and quite importantly: where have you isolated the problem in your code and what have you tried to do to fix it but ended up not getting it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reassigning the `H` variable in the line below.

```
H = H-(0.5*9.8*Math.pow(t,2));
```

Replace that line with the one below to get the right output.

```
double H_new = H-(0.5*9.8*Math.pow(t,2));
```

Don't forget to change the variable in your `println` call too:

```
System.out.println(t + "\t\t" + H_new + "\t\t" + velocity);
```

---

This way, the `H` variable stays equal to the user's input and your calculation isn't affected by the results of the previous calculation.

---

Output:

```
 t(s)       Height(m)       Velocity(m/s)
------------------------------------------
0       1234.56     0.0
1       1229.6599999999999      9.8
2       1214.96     19.6
3       1190.46     29.400000000000002
4       1156.1599999999999      39.2
5       1112.06     49.0
6       1058.1599999999999      58.800000000000004
7       994.4599999999999       68.60000000000001
8       920.9599999999999       78.4
9       837.6599999999999       88.2
10      744.56      98.0
11      641.6599999999999       107.80000000000001
12      528.9599999999999       117.60000000000001
13      406.4599999999999       127.4
14      274.15999999999985      137.20000000000002
15      132.05999999999995      147.0
```

As for the issue of repeating digits, try using the `DecimalFormat` class.